# elf32-littlearm symbol format unrecognized debugging Native Android code

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I'm trying to debug some native Android code built through the NDK. Unfortunately, when I launch the process under the debugger from Eclipse I get an error

```
I'm sorry, Dave, I can't do that.  Symbol format `elf32-littlearm' unknown.
```

The code is compiled for ARM thumb so the symbol format makes sense. However, using Google's bundled ADT for Eclipse should work? Do I need to specify a specific version of GDB to use?

To note, the code runs fine without trying to debug.

I'm running on Windows 7 64 bit with NDK release 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching it looks like it is a bug with the GDB shipped with the NDK r10 toolchain. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74371. The [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axlbq2xnqhxmvwe/android-ndk-r10-windows-x86_64-gdb.tar.xz) linked from that bug seems to work for me.